# Google Maps API - blank frame on my dev environment, not on environment of colleague

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Currently I am working on an Android app that's making use of the Google Maps API. The Android app is being correctly displayed when my colleague runs the project from his laptop, but when I try to run in from my laptop on the same device the frame with Google Maps in it keeps blank like you can see in the image below. I have installed the same packages in the SDK manager as my colleague, so what else could be the reason why the Google Maps frame keeps being blank?

Images:

**Google_Maps**

[image]

**SDK_Manager**

[image]

Comment: same problem like me..   i just develop new project and change api key and copy all logic from older project nd its working fine.., problem is with api key maybe..

Comment: Can u check ur logcat any warnings are there?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is problem of SHA1 key and package name not added in adroid map key in developer console so please check or add your laptop sha1 key in android key in developer console.
more information read this link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert